# req.user undefined when using $http with angularJS, express and passport

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, passport.js

I've run into a problem where `req.user` is undefined when making an API call with $http in angularJS.  The strange thing is that if I login with Postman and then make a call to my protected endpoint, `req.user` is defined and authentication is working as expected.

Protected endpoint `/activities` (this is where req.user is undefined when using $http):

```
var isAuthenticated = function (req, res, next) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated())
        return next();
    res.redirect(process.env.BASE_CLIENT_URL + 'login');
}

router.get('/activities', isAuthenticated, activityController.getActivities);
```

Angular Controller that I redirect to after a successful passport login, basically on load of this page I make a call to my `/activities` endpoint:

```
angular.module('myApp.view2', ['ngRoute'])

  .config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/view2', {
      templateUrl: 'view2/view2.html',
      controller: 'View2Ctrl'
    });
  }])

  .controller('View2Ctrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {

    $scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function (event) {
      $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'http://localhost:8000/api/activities',
        withCredentials: true
      }).then(function successCallback(response) {
        console.log("Success!");
      }, function errorCallback(response) {
        console.log("Error");
      });
    });
  }]);
```

Any thoughts?  I'm not sure why it would be working as expected through an API client such as Postman but not working in my angularJS app, am I missing certain headers?

Thanks!

**Update:**

**Headers from $http request:**

```
accept:"application/json, text/plain, */*"
accept-encoding:"gzip, deflate, br"
accept-language:"en-US,en;q=0.9"
cache-control:"no-cache"
connection:"keep-alive"
cookie:"connect.sid=s%3AFvUCnqkLyGKh6rZh41nU0oXDFiRpu3pZ.74Oit3DNmizkCyvGId1%2F%2FNbLQlichVM6HEHfh3MLS3g"
host:"localhost:8000"
pragma:"no-cache"
referer:"http://localhost:8000/"
user-agent:"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.121 Safari/537.36"
```

**Headers from Restlet:**

```
{"params":{"headers":["Host: localhost:8000","Connection: keep-alive","User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.96 Safari/537.36","Accept: */*","Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br","Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9","Cookie: [331 bytes were stripped]","If-None-Match: W/\"44faa272a8181008d08c6051967c5c38\""],"line":"GET /api/activities HTTP/1.1\r\n"},"phase":0,"source":{"id":819156,"type":1},"time":"496058853","type":159}
```

Might be an issue with the login when running it via the app.  If I login with Postman and THEN make the call to my `/activities` endpoint, it is successful.  However, performing the login and making the call to the `/activities` endpoint via my app is when I run into the issue.

Comment: Try to use dev-tools and see the network request made by Postman, and compare it to the one made by angular. what are the differences between the two?

Comment: You are trying to redirect an Ajax request, the client side (the one that made that ajax request) won't redirect to that url.

Comment: Updated to show headers for $http and Restlet